# Enhanced grid pagination throwing invalid argument error on dialog and portlet dialog settings

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, portlet

I am using dojox/widget/portlet,dojox/widget/PortletDialogSettings and dijit/Dialog for my webpage. These portlets and dialogs all have enhanced grid within. I have other similar widgets with these three types in the same page but they are working fine. 
Issue is with current widget only.

The enhanced grids uses pagination.

```
var plug = plugins: {
    pagination: {
    pageSizes: ["7", "14", "28", "All"],
    description: true,
    sizeSwitch: true,
    pageStepper: true,
    gotoButton: true,
    maxPageStep: 4,
    defaultPageSize:7,
    position: "bottom"
                }
            }
```

When I click on maximize/try to open the dialog, I get below error in dojo.js.
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
File: dojo.js, Line: 15, Column: 87982

The code corresponding to the error message isin the below function in dojo.js.

```
             _3a0.set = function setStyle(node,name,_3b2){
            var n=dom.byId(node),l=arguments.length,op=(name=="opacity");
            name=_3b1[name]?"cssFloat" in n.style?"cssFloat":"styleFloat":name;
            if(l==3){
                return op?_3a9(n,_3b2):n.style[name]=_3b2;
            }
            for(var x in name){
                _3a0.set(node,x,name[x]);
            }
            return _3a0.getComputedStyle(n);
        };
        return _3a0;
    });
}
```

The error points exactly at `return op?_3a9(n,_3b2):n.style[name]=_3b2;` in above function. 
When I removed the pagination for the grid in dialog/portlet dialog, the grid comes but without pagination iot throws the mentioned error. But i require pagination for the grids.
The grid is defined as

```
var gridProd = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
id: 'gridProd',
store: store,
structure: layout,
nestedSorting: true,
rowSelector: '1px',
plugins:plug
}, document.createElement('div'));
dojo.byId("gridProdDiv").appendChild(gridProd.domNode);
gridProd.startup();
```

Please help me to figure out what is causing the issue.